# How to print key character code in OSX?

Tags: macos, keycode

I learned from somewhere that I can reset keybindings of keyboard in OSX.
like:

```
{
    "\UF72C"  = "moveToBeginningOfLine:";
}
```

I used a keycode of up key to test and it works well. Now I want to bind another key but I don't know the character code of the key, so is there a script or some other code I can use to display the character code of any key I pressed?

Comment: There was an utility called `keycode` on the store...

Comment: This looks useful: http://www.cocoabits.com/KeyBindingsEditor/

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  thanks, key codes works well, but how can I close the question

Comment: You don't close a question on SO, just accept an answer as "the answer". but I've just make a comment...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès  Yes, I mean that there is no answer to accept. Can you add your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? :)

Comment: Kind of you! Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an utility called `keycode` on the store...